# Electron js - Divs are unclickable until the screen is maximized- after that the situation is normal

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

I have some code working to make 2 div tags visible only when another div is clicked (an attempt to make a custom title bar)The 2 divs are invisible initially.

```js
const {remote} = require('electron');
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
win.setSize(810,610);
function max(){
    var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    
    if(win.isMaximized()){
        win.unmaximize();
        document.getElementById('file').style.right = "744px";
        document.getElementById('about_us').style.right = "664px";
    }else{
        win.maximize();
        document.getElementById('file').style.right = "1314px";
        document.getElementById('about_us').style.right = "1234px";
    }
    
}

hidden = true;
function get(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function open_file_menu(){
    var fileMenu = [get('file_menu'),get('file_menu2')];
    if (hidden == false){
        for (i = 0;i<fileMenu.length;i++){
            fileMenu[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            hidden = true;
        }
        
    }
    else{
        for (i = 0;i<fileMenu.length;i++){
            fileMenu[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
            hidden = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body,html{
  width: 47.5pc;
  height: 100pc;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-app-region:drag; 
  z-index: 0;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
  z-index: 1;
}
#container{
  width: 100pc;
  height: 100pc;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 0;
  
}

#container nav{
  display: grid;
  width: 100pc;
  height: 2.2pc;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 1;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  color:#dacbcb;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color: #222222;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  transition: ease-in-out 1ms;
  -webkit-app-region:no-drag; 
}
#buttons{
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  
}
#maximize{
  transform: translateX(-124px);
}
#maximize span:hover,#minimize:hover span,.menu1:hover,.menu2:hover{
  background-color: #333333;
}
#file{
  position: absolute;
  right:743px;
}
#about_us{
  position: absolute;
  right:663px;

#run{
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
.menu1{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.menu2{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
#file_menu{
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #222222;
  transform: translateY(34px);
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
#file_menu2{
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #222222;
  transform: translateY(63px);
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.fm{
  z-index: 2;
}
#file_menu:hover,#file_menu2:hover{
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="text_editor.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Extorc App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div onclick="uff()">
      <span id = "file_menu" class = "fm">new</span> 
    </div>
    <div>
      <span id = "file_menu2" class = "fm">open</span> 
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <nav>
        <div id="buttons">
          <div id="file" onclick="open_file_menu()">
            <span class = "menu1">file</span> 
          </div>
          <div id="about_us">
            <span class = "menu2">about..us</span>
          </div>
          <div id="maximize" onclick="max()">
            <span>+</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code works ... the menu opens up with 2 divs displaying but the divs are un clickable or probably totally passive (i have set a `:hover` background color in my css)Though , this problem ends if i open the 2 divs and then maximize the window..then they become interactable and then after minimizing also they work which means the divs are un-interactable initially but then after one maximize , they work...any fix for that....should i not use visibility here?

**Edit** Not only by fullscreen but also if i resize the window , the buttons start working , and starting the window as `fullscreen : true,` doesnt make it work

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code. The fastest way to resolve your problem is for you to recreate a minimum example without electron and post it as a snippet.

Comment: @szydlovski i have posted my code without the electrons js file.......tbh i dont really know how lesser can i trim it down to,i did remove some repeated menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put all the body as draggable: `-webkit-app-region:drag;` on `body,html`

You will have to define a specific area where it defined as draggable.

My recommendation define a specific area / SVG that means drag and don't put clickables on it.

E.g take a look at known electron products (VSCODE, Slack) you have specific regions from which you can drag from.

Hope I have helped.